# Why wont jsoup find a simple p element in this wikipedia page?

Tags: java, netbeans, web, screen-scraping, jsoup

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class SWS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scrapeTopic("/wiki/Python");
    }

    public static void scrapeTopic(String url) {
        String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/" + url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String contentText = doc.select("p").first().text();
        System.out.println(contentText);
    }

    public static String getUrl(String Url) {
        URL urlObj = null;

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(Url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("The url was malformed");
            return "";
        }

        URLConnection urlCon = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String outputText = "";

        try {
            urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlCon.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputText += line;
            }

            in.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem connecting to the url");
            return "";
        }

        return outputText;
    }
}
```

Other people have tried it and it works but not for me. The only thing that will work is when I use `"*"` but that returns the whole page and in the wrong format eg
�}k��q�g�h6c��y����(� ...

I have also tried `"mw-content-text > p"` and this is definitely in the wiki page.

I apologize for anyone who keeps laying eyes on this code but I cant seem to scrape even the simplest of things in the html page.

This is the output I receive when using "p" in the select method:

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at sws.SWS.scrapeTopic(SWS.java:43)
    at sws.SWS.main(SWS.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

---

line 43 is:

```
String contentText = doc.select("p").first().text();
```

and line 27 is:

```
scrapeTopic("/wiki/Python");
```

I am using Netbeans at the moment. I'm not sure if this is relevant but  Netbeans is underlining the folowing line in yellow with the message "The assigned value is never used"

```
URL urlObj = null;
URLConnection urlCon = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
String line = "";
```

Like I said, it seems to work for others and not for me!
Thanks In advance!

Comment: The URL is en.wikipedia.org (for English pages), not www.wikipedia.org. You should fix that.

Comment: Thank you @RobinGreen! That has solved the problem! So the URL was wrong all this time. Thats annoying! I got the url from a tutorial I was following. I gues next time I should go get the URL for myself ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is en.wikipedia.org (for English pages), not www.wikipedia.org.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you just let jsoup connect to the wikipedia page.

```
public static void scrapeTopic(String url)
{

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wikipedia.org/" + url).get();
        String contentText = doc.select("p").first().text();
        System.out.println(contentText);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```